# How can I change guilayout.label font size?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
private void OnGUI()
    {
        GUIStyle myStyle = new GUIStyle();
        myStyle.fontSize = 20;

        GUILayout.BeginVertical(GUI.skin.box);
        GUILayout.Label("Replacing");
        GUI.Label(new Rect(650, 650, 300, 50), "HELLO WORLD", myStyle);
    }
```

I see the Replacing label but it's font very small. So I wanted to test changing the size using new Rect but I don't see the HELLO WORLD anywhere.

Comment: You don't see the "HELLO WORLD" because it's out of your screen. change `y` of `Rect` to 0 to see the text :)

Comment: Also, stop using OnGUI and use [the new UI](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/the-new-ui).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Text` is showing but not visible to you because of the values you passed to the `Rect` struct. The value of 650 and 650 that is passed to the `Rect` struct in the `x`,`y` argument seem to be bigger than the actual screen size. Reduce it to about 100 and you should be able to see the `Text`:

```
GUI.Label(new Rect(100, 100, 300, 20), "Hello World!", myStyle);
```

If you want your UI display to be dynamic, I suggest you use `Screen.height` and `Screen.height` to determine where to place the GUI element and make sure that it works regardless the size of the screen.

For example:

```
GUI.Label(new Rect(Screen.height / 2, Screen.height / 2, 300, 20), "Hello World!", myStyle);
```

Finally, I assume this is an Editor code based on your other questions. If it's not then you should be using the new UI system with the [`Text`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Text.html) component.

Answer (score 5):

I am using two options:
this

```
GUIStyle headStyle = new GUIStyle();
headStyle.fontSize = 30; 
GUI.Label(new Rect(Screen.width / 3, Screen.height / 2, 300, 50), "HELLO WORLD", headStyle);
```

or this

```
GUI.skin.label.fontSize = 30;
GUILayout.Label("HELLO WORLD", GUILayout.Width(300), GUILayout.Height(50)))
```